# How to Stream Video from Http or RTSP Url in android

Tags: android, rtsp, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, android-videoview

I want to play a video from Http and Rtsp on android. currently i am trying with http link But when my activity starts, it just starts playing audio with blank black screen. No video is displaying. Here i have posted my code below. Thanks for any help in advance. and if anyone can provide a fresh running rtsp link for live streaming, i'll be very thankful.

```
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

    Uri stream = Uri.parse("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp");

    vidView.setVideoURI(stream);

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    vidView.requestFocus();
    vidView.start();
```

Comment: You can use [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21522333/2591002) use Vitamino library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do it via [Vitamio Libary](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle). *Vitamio supports 720p/1080p HD, mp4, mkv, m4v, mov, flv, avi, rmvb, rm, ts, tp and many other video formats in Android and iOS.* Almost all popular streaming protocols are supported by Vitamio, including HLS (m3u8), MMS, RTSP, RTMP, and HTTP.

You can download demo from [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/master/vitamio-sample).

Comment: i just tried Vitamio Library as u suggested. but when i am trying to play a video, its playing very slow. i am trying this link [link](https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4) and its working smooth and fine in my PC's web browser.

Comment: the problem is that i was testing this on emulator, its working perfect on real device. i am gonna mark this one as answer.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the VideoView does not work with your stream then you need to do it with ffmpeg