# Stream an audio file to multiple android phones

Tags: android, audio, rtp

I'm want to make an app that would let users connect to other android devices and play music on all devices simultaneously(much like Samsung's Group Play). I did a little reading over the internet and learnt that the MediaPlayer in android can do rtsp. I'm not exactly sure what it is or how it works, but it seems that it can help me stream audio. I want to know how I could

1.Set up a kind of a server that all devices would connect to.

2.Get a client to connect to the "server". Multiple clients would connect.

3.Stream audio to all connected clients.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: this is a very broad question, you could literally break it down into three based on your 3 points and  those would probably still be too broad to address in one answer. it's best if you give it a shot and then post issues with what your tried here.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start from.. The more I read. I tried reading, but I'm still very unclear what and where to start. Any suggestions as to where I can start from?

Comment: I have used the library "Libstreaming" to send live video streams using the RTSP protocol between two android phones before, you might want to start off by looking at that.The library itself is very easy to use.

Comment: google 'android mediaplayer example rtp', one stackoverflow previous question in those search results is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005209/implement-rtp-stream-media-player-on-android-device

Comment: Can I stream audio using the same?

Comment: @hello_world It can stream AAC audio

Comment: Mp3? Or any other audio formats?